# Outlook 2007 - Can't Delete Personal Accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have Win7 Pro 64bit running Office 2007.  I am an IT trainer and train end users on Office. I understand the basics of home user accounts and pst files.

In Outlook I had set up 3 accounts: - Barry’s mail, Marta’s mail, Kevin’s mail.

I was having issues with my Barry’s mail account as I could not set it to the default, plus outlook was not always able to connect to this account.

So I decided to backup/save my outlook.pst file and delete all of Office 2007 and start again.

I used the Control Panel / Programs and Features / MS Office 2007 / Uninstall procedure but this does NOT remove all the files on the system so I also manually removed the Outlook files that were left on the system.

I reinstalled Office 2007, did not put the old pst file back in place and started Outlook but it kept asking for the pst file (so I obviously had been unsuccessful in hoping for a fresh install).

I put the old pst file back in place and Outlook opened OK however where the 3 personal accounts were (Barry, Marta, Kevin) there are now 3 unnamed folders that also show in the account settings as unnamed accounts. I deleted these accounts but they reappear when I reopen Outlook.

How do I get rid of these accounts?

Comment: Where did you delete the pst files from?

Comment: You delete the registry information that handles the accounts.  Since I know the next question your going to ask: http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/526701/#msg_526701

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the files again as you have.

When Outlook opens, take a note of the name of the file it wants.

Open control panel, click on Mail. Click on Data Files and add a new file with the same file  name. This will create an empty pst file for you and should appease Outlook.